# if clause not working

Tags: bash, shell

from the below code i am traversing through each file and checking if my filename matches lower case and special characters and also check if it is less than 20 chars, but apparently my if clause does not seem to work. Could somebody suggest?

```
#/bin/bash
Count=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
echo $Count
if [[ ( $Count -ge 2 ) && ( $count -lt 1000 ) ]]
   then
        for file in *;
        do
                if [[ $file == [a-z0-9._-] && ${#file} -le 20 ]];
                echo "inside if $file ${#file}"
           then
                [ -f "$file" ] || continue
                #Check the extension of the file
                ext="${file##*.}"
                #check if the file name is ending with .txt push to text directory
                if [ $ext == "txt" ]
                then
                        mkdir -p text
                        mv $file text
                fi
                #if bash scripts are there push to scripts directory
                if [ $ext == "sh" ]
                then
                        mkdir -p Scripts
                        mv $file Scripts
                fi
                #if log scripts are there push to log directory
                if [ $ext == "log" ]
                then
                        mkdir -p logs
                        mv $file logs
                fi
                #if music files are there push to music directory
                if [[ $ext == "mp3" || $ext == "flac" ]]
                then
                        mkdir -p Music
                        mv $file Music
                fi
          fi
        done
fi
```

Comment: `Count` and `count` are two different variables.  Globbing patterns always matches the whole query string,  so `$file == *[some set]*` rather than `$file == [some set]`. Also note that you will get the wrong count if any filename contains newlines. It is unclear in what specific way your code "does not work".  It's also unclear whether you think that the `find` command is finding the same files that you iterate over in your loop, or what your overall goal with your script is.

Comment: Or maybe `[[ $file != [^a-z0-9._-] ]]` if you want to check that there's nothing but `a-z0-9._-`

Answer (score 1):

There are several minor syntax problems here (most of which [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out -- recommended!), but let me start with the biggest problems:

```
if [[ $file == [a-z0-9._-] && ${#file} -le 20 ]];
   echo "inside if $file ${#file}"
then
    ...
```

The first problem here is that the glob pattern `[a-z0-9._-]` matches *a single character*. If the filename is more than one character long, it won't match. If you want to make sure the filename consists only of characters from that set, use a regular expression test instead: `$file =~ ^[a-z0-9._-]+$` (note that inside a `[[ ]]` expression `=` and `==` do glob pattern matching, and `=~` does regex matching). You can also roll the length check into this with `$file =~ ^[a-z0-9._-]{1,20}$` (the `{1,20}` means "between 1 and 20 of the previous thing").

The second problem is that when there is more than one command between `if` and `then`, it's the status of *the last one* that determines whether the expression is considered true or false. The `echo` command pretty much always succeeds, so the expression is true, and the `then` clause almost always gets executed. I'd recommend either moving that `echo` somewhere else, or just removing it entirely.

Now, for the minor problems: the shebang (first line) should start with `#!`, not just `#`. `Count` and `count` are different variables (capitalization matters!). Inside a `[ ]` test, you should double-quote variables to avoid weird parsing, and `==` is nonstandard, so for example use `[ "$ext" = "txt" ]` instead of `[ $ext == "txt" ]`. Also, you should double-quote variables pretty much everywhere else, to, e.g. `echo "$Count"` and `mv "$file" text`.

Finally, I'd be tempted to replace the section that extracts the extension and then uses a series of `if` statements based on it with a single `case` statement (this is pretty much what `case` is intended for):

```
case "$file" in
    *.txt )
         mkdir -p text
         mv "$file" text ;;

    *.sh )
         mkdir -p Scripts
         mv "$file" Scripts ;;

    *.log )
         mkdir -p logs
         mv "$file" logs ;;

    *.mp3 | *.flac )
         mkdir -p Music
         mv "$file" Music ;;
esac
```